# Javascript to turn an unordered list into multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There doesn't seem to be an easy way in (well supported) css to do this. I'm looking for a javascript solution, preferably jQuery.

I have an unordered list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>        
    ...etc
</ul>
```

I want each column to have a height for example four items and fill vertically rather than horizontally like a css float:

```
A     E
B     F
C
D
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this has to be a `ul`? Seems to me that if you have rows and columns, you have tabular content, and you need a table.

Comment: To give you a little context this is a list of links. Tables are meant for tabular data I agree. This is a list of one type of data (links), essentially like a single column from a table. How is that tabular?

By using a list I am separating the layout to within the javascript rather than the html. If the css/javascript is lost the page will have a nicely nested list instead of stupid tables.

Comment: Here's a live example of how to do it in jquery: jsfiddle.net/EebVF/5 Using this jquery plugin: github.com/fzondlo/jquery-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doug's solution is nice if you want to split the list up into sub lists.

Instead I chose to position the list elements without changing the dom.
This is a bit messy, basically it puts a left margin on each element which is the column number multiplied by the column width.
This will result in a staircase layout so the next step was to add some negative top margin to bring each element up to the top.

Basically this displays as a grid. I am using this for drop down menus so it worked well. Avoid using this if you need each list item to have a dynamic height. The col_height variable could be set to the height of the largest item to make the code a bit more general purpose.

```
var col_max_height = 6; //Max Items per column
var col_width = 200; //Pixels
var col_height = 33; //Pixels
$('.header ul li ul').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').each(function(index){
        column = parseInt(index/col_max_height);
        $(this).css('margin-left', column * col_width + 'px')
        if(column > 0) {
            $(this).css('margin-top', (index - (col_max_height * column)  + 1) * -col_height + 'px').addClass('col_'+column);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How would you set this up to start at the top of every new column? Now when the next colum have eg 2 <li> items then they will show on the bottom instead of the top. So basically you have to start with "margin-top:-300px" and so on. But how can you do that?

Answer (score 10):

You will want to use a combination of CSS and jQuery, but in theory it is very simple. Render a complete single list in HTML, then provide a wrapper via jQuery and split the list up as desired. The following function does just that. Be sure to use a more specific selector than just `ul` when actually using the script. An `id` would be ideal.

[View demo here.](https://jsbin.com/zaxoji/edit?html,js,output)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var size = 4,
      $ul  = $("ul"),
      $lis = $ul.children().filter(':gt(' + (size - 1) + ')'),
      loop = Math.ceil($lis.length / size),
      i    = 0;

  $ul.css('float', 'left').wrap("<div style='overflow: hidden'></div>");

  for (; i < loop; i = i + 1) {
    $ul = $("<ul />").css('float', 'left').append($lis.slice(i * size, (i * size) + size)).insertAfter($ul);
  }
});
```

Comment: Not quite what I need, but none the less a nice solution. Much simpler than some of the jQuery column plugins.

+1 Good work.

Comment: @Keyo, is the list supposed to fill dynamically?

Comment: No, but I just don't want to change any of my existing css. I am using a dropdown menu, suckerfish style.

By splitting it into 3 lists it would create 3 menu links. 

I guess it would be invalid to wrap a whole bunch of <li> within a div?

My solution below works, but it's not the cleanest I admit.

Comment: This is fantastic, I needed the same thing for rows instead of columns so I adjusted the code: http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/8MQa8/ Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

See this article:

> One of the minor holy grails of XHTML
> and CSS is to produce a single,
> semantically logical ordered list that
> wraps into vertical columns.
>
> I’ll warn you up front. If you want to
> present a list in multiple columns,
> you’ll have to compromise. You can
> sacrifice W3C web standards and use
> deprecated markup, you can live with
> markup that’s less than semantically
> logical, you can tolerate a mixture of
> presentation with content, you can say
> goodbye to browser compatibility, or
> you can use markup that’s heavy with
> attributes and styling that’s heavy
> with rules. Every road exacts a toll.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

The "best" solution is subjective, but I'd be inclined towards arbitrary classes.

Comment: I read that before asking here. It's a very good article and I went with a javascript fix because it's not a huge issue if it degrades and I don't want make the html messy.

Unfortunately Alist didn't provide any js solution.

Answer (score 2):

@Keyo, thanks for your helpful answer.

Just a few modification needed to make it work on my end. 
(Formula was changed, perhaps it could help someone)

```
var col_max_item = 2; //Max Items per column
var col_width = $('.header ul li').css('width').replace("px", "");  //Pixels, get width from CSS
var col_height = $('.header ul li').css('height').replace("px", ""); //Pixels, get height from CSS  

    $('.header ul').each(function() { 
        $(this).find('li').each(function(index){ 
            column = parseInt(index/col_max_item);
            $(this).css('margin-left', column * col_width + 'px')
            if(column > 0 && (index / col_max_item) == column) {
                $(this).css('margin-top', (col_max_item * col_height * -1)  + 'px').addClass('col_'+column);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

for this I use a plugin called "Easy List Splitter". here is the link:

http://www.madeincima.it/en/articles/resources-and-tools/easy-list-splitter-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Just a little different moves up the next column instead of each li.

```
var col_max_height = 6; //Max Items per column
var col_width = 120; //Pixels
var prevCol = 0; 
$('.header ul').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').each(function(index){
    column = parseInt(index/col_max_height);
    $(this).css('margin-left', column * col_width + 'px')
        if(prevCol != column) {
            $(this).css('margin-top',  '-92px').addClass('col_'+column);
            prevCol = column;
        } else {
            $(this).css('margin-top',  '0px').addClass('col_'+column);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this really easily with the [jQuery-Columns Plugin](http://github.com/fzondlo/jquery-columns) for example to split a ul with a class of .mylist you would do

```
$('.mylist').cols(2);
```

Here's a [live example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EebVF/5)