# Is there a JQuery Expression that will target a div which doesn't have a stipulated class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Im using tabber.js ([www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/)) to create a list of tabs then I'm using a columniser function to columnise the information in the tabs.

However my jquery selector isnt working: $('("div.tabberlive div").not(".tabbertabhide") ul'). I had $('div.tabbertab ul') which I thought would work on all tabs and show as normal but it columnised the hidden tabs and showed them as well. I am hoping that making it more specific to the div which is visible (which has no unique class to target unfortunately) would help.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="tabberlive">
  <ul class="tabbernav">...</ul>
  <div class="tabbertab "><ul>...</ul></div>
  <div class="tabbertab tabbertabhide"><ul>...</ul></div>
  <div class="tabbertab tabbertabhide"><ul>...</ul></div>
  <div class="tabbertab tabbertabhide"><ul>...</ul></div>
</div>
```

The columniser function is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var size = 6,
      $ul  = $('("div.tabberlive div").not(".tabbertabhide") ul'),
      $lis = $ul.children().filter(':gt(' + (size - 1) + ')'),
      loop = Math.ceil($lis.length / size),
      i    = 0;

  $ul.css('float', 'left').wrap("<div style='overflow: hidden'></div>");

  for (; i < loop; i = i + 1) {
    $ul = $("<ul />").css('float', 'left').append($lis.slice(i * size, (i * size) + 6)).insertAfter($ul);
  }
});
```

Ive tried to guess the selector but obviously failed... any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the good syntax.

You may use this :

```
$('div.tabberlive div:not(.tabbertabhide) ul')
```

Alternatively you could use

```
$('div.tabberlive div').not('.tabbertabhide').find('ul')
```

[not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) lets you filter a jQuery set by removing the unwanted elements.

[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) gives you the matching elements among the descendants.

Comment: Cheers for the syntax correction! I no longer get any errors but its not columnising the list items any more?

Comment: Without the goal and the exact HTML, I'd just recommend you to debug step by step your loop. But it's almost certainly much too complicated for your need.

Comment: Why do you use filter(:gt on the $ul.children() ? Obviously you know the slice function.

Comment: +1 .. Just as a side note to those who might not know, dystroy's first option will normally be more optimal than the second. Sizzle will only collect decendants that match the `:not` whilst collecting `div.tabberlive div` items, and not filter them out after having collected all `div.tabberlive div` items.

Comment: Sorry to credit where I found it: Doug Neiner posted the columniser function above as a solution to the following problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225346/javascript-to-turn-an-unordered-list-into-multiple-columns

Comment: Well the fiddler version of this works if this helps anyone. Must be my own set up conflicting with it: http://jsfiddle.net/CsBwM/. Thanks very much dystroy

Comment: This may or may not be useful to anyone else's set up. I copied the rendered code from fiddler for the jQuery and found the CDATA and window.load wrap useful around the document ready. Still cant work out why it was running with the less specific jQuery selector without these but required them for the more specific selector? This could be a sizzle anomaly or just an odd configuration on the site I was using. Thanks to @dystroy for his help and pebbl for his optimisation recommendation.