# Long Ul in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Ul with 40-200 `li`. I currently have it in one column but I want it to automatically make 2+ columns based on the amount of `li` present so it fits the screen.

I had success with splitting the `ul` manually into 2 sets and making each a row but then in the mobile screen it adds a huge white space between the 2 `ul`s. Any help is wonderful.

```html
<div  class="container-fluid contentContainer marginTop" id="topContainer" style="margin-bottom:0 px">
  <div class="row">
   <div  class="col-md-6 " id="topRow">
    <ul  class="dl-multicolumn" id="list">
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('2974')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>AA Latin Upfront Commisison </font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('2941')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>AA/BA/IB/AY Transatlantic Global Upfront Commission</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3295')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>AA/Qantas Oceanic Upfront</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('2943')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>AA/US/BA/IB Preferred Upfront Commission</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('2942')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>AA/US/BA/IB/AY Transatlantic OneWorld Upfront</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3344')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>AC Pacific TOT Upfront Commission</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3343')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>AC Transborder/within Canada ticket by 6/30/2016</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3182')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>Aerolineas Argentina 2015 ticket by 31DEC2015</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('2857')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>Austrian Air Layover Offers</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('2961')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>Avianca – Net Fares – Apollo Formats</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('2960')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>Avianca – Net Fares – Sabre Formats</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3046')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>BA/IB Soft Dollar Fund -Waivers and Favors Program</font></a></li>
        
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3020')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>British Air Group Deposits</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3134')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>British Air Seat Assignment Instructions</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3364')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>Cathay Pacific - commission contract</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3268')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>Cathay Pacific HKG/HIJ/HKG add-on after 16AUG15 </font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3064')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>El AL Ticket through 12/31/2015</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('2849')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>Emirates Chauffeur Drive Services</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3368')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>EVA AIR 8% plus $80.00 UPFRONT</font></a></li>
     
     <li><A class="LinksRoll" href="javascript:openDocument('3166')"><font face='Tahoma' size='3'>EVA Air Intra Asia through 30NOV15</font></a></li>
    

    </ul> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It looks like @Doug has a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3225412/4793915

Comment: If you're happy with the `li`s going across rather than down and ok to get rid of that awful bootstrap (despite how popular it is) then you can do this very easily just by setting all the `li`s to `float:left`

Comment: What about simply adding columns: https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/

Comment: Nice info about 'columns'.  Here's some more info to show compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS3%20Multiple%20column%20layout